# Can I use java8 language for Robolectric tests, while using java7 for the app?

Tags: android, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

Basically, I want to use all the java8 features for unit tests, since they run on the jvm, while maintaining compatibility for app by only using java7 language features.

However, I only see one place in build.gradle where I can set the language version, and it applies to both the app and its tests.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds trivial but I would go with the retrolambda plugin that allows you to write app in java8.

It is also possible to achieve with two Gradle files with different language levels, but still the experience of usage these files will be quite unpleasant.